# Declare angular factories residing in different files

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have defined 2 angular factories in files fact1.js and fact2.js

fact1.js:

```
angular.module('myapp').factory('fact1', function ($rootScope) {
return $rootScope.userid;
});
```

fact2.js:

```
angular.module('myapp').factory('fact2', function ($rootScope) {
return $rootScope.role;
});
```

app.js has:

```
angular.module('myapp', [
'ngCookies',
'ngResource',
'ngSanitize',
'ngRoute'
])
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
 // config and run methods
```

All these are in different js files and I am loading them in index.html as:

```
<body ng-app="myapp">
<!-- code to load angular components -->

<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services/fact1.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services/fact2.js"></script>
<!-- Load other components -->
```

The factories remain undefined. I saw couple of examples on [how to declare a factory](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) when declaring the module itself, but how can I declare them when they reside in different files?

EDIT:
code for mycontroller.js which injects and uses these factories:

```
angular.module('myapp').controller('mycontroller', function (fact1,fact2) {
console.log("UserID is:" + fact1);
console.log("UserRole is:" + fact2);
});
```

Comment: You've accidentally given the factories the same name... And could you explain "undefined"?  Do you get an error when you inject your factories, or is the VALUE just undefined?

Comment: So when I inject these factories in controllers and use it, I get error message stating it cannot read property from "undefined". I'll edit the question to put up code for injection and its usage.

Comment: @pbd [Here is a working version on CodePen](http://codepen.io/rossmartin/pen/AqrKw).  I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're declaring the separate modules that you're loading in as the same module name, 'myapp'.

Try doing the following in your factory files, assuming you want to keep them separate:

```
angular.module('myapp.factory1').factory('fact1', function ($rootScope) {
  return $rootScope.userid;
});

angular.module('myapp.factory2').factory('fact2', function ($rootScope) {
  return $rootScope.role;
});
```

Then do this in your app.js or central file:

```
angular.module('myapp', [
 'myapp.factory1',
 'myapp.factory2',
  ...
 'ngSanitize',
 'ngRoute'
])
```

That should do the trick. The issue is that your factories aren't being declared as dependencies correctly.

Comment: This answer does not solve the problem as it's presented in the question currently - the OP is not loading the factories in separate modules, nor are they defining them as such. While I'm glad they worked out a solution, I'm downvoting the question because it lacks value for others.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the `$rootScope` dependency

```
angular.module('myapp').factory('fact1', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    return $rootScope.userid;
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not because of different files. Factory definition looks correct. But it is not obvious from your code where you assign values to $rootScope.role and $rootScope.userid. You could get undefined for factories if $rootScope.role and $rootScope.userid are not set. Or you mean injector could not resolve it?

Edit: there is simplified version of your code  http://jsfiddle.net/hUhpB/1/

```
angular.module('myapp', []).run(function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.userid = 3;
});

angular.module('myapp').factory('fact1', function ($rootScope) {
    return $rootScope.userid;
});

angular.module('myapp').controller('TestCtrl', function(fact1){
    alert(fact1);
});
```

It works as expected, moving code to external files doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clear. I am setting $rootScope values in module.run() method. So, they are assigned when "myapp" loads.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've posted, the problem would not be in your use of separate files. In fact, it's hard to say what the problem is based on the information & code provided. But [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/X4UOrCpIbZH02FjqPlKj?p=preview) works and it follows very closely how you've structured the code posted in your question.

My suggestion is to take a look at it alongside of your actual development code and compare the two to see where the problem might be. I bet it's in some code you either haven't posted here or have mistranscribed.